# Limit of the size of result set

Tags: support, data-explorer

I am trying to [get a list of users that made at least one post](https://data.stackexchange.com/ell/query/1206636).

By "an user *made at least one post*", I mean there is at least one post linked to this user, and there are 7k posts on ELL having a `NULL` OwnerUserId.

With this snippet

```
SELECT COUNT(id) as post_count, OwnerUserId
FROM posts
group by OwnerUserId
order by post_count desc
```

I got 24562 rows, which is far less than the actual number of users, I guess it is because of some kind of SQL/SEDE limit of the size of resultset.

I've checked [Microsoft documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/reference/setmaxrows-method-sqlserverstatement?view=sql-server-ver15) but no luck.

How do I get a complete list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *is* a complete list. Not every user has posted a question or answer. The users corresponding to a `NULL` `OwnerUserId` have been deleted, so the 'community' owns them now.

There *is* a limit of the number of results in SEDE, but it's [50000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/269063/295232) and only applied at the end, when showing the results, so it doesn't affect your query.